# Loading a remote file into Power BI

Tags: csv, powerbi, remote-access

Hi I currently have a Power BI Pro licence and want to load one .CSV file from a remote Linux server into a power BI application.

Is this even possible with Power BI?, I have done some research into this and am struggling to find any hard documentation.

If this is possible what are the steps in achieving this?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: How do you access the remote file? A file share?  FTP?

Comment: To access the remote file I SSH into the remote server @Degan

Comment: I expect that you will need to script retrieving your file using your SSH client first.  Likely, you could use PowerShell and script the SSH retrieval then the Power BI data manipulation/presentation.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can try loading your CSV using R/Python programs. I invoke R script from PowerBI, which converts CSV file into R dataframe and sends it back to PowerBI.
For Ex-

Input File - inp.csv

Unix server name - abc@xyz.com

R script name - import.R

I select 'R script' method in Power BI and use below code:

```
 source("/abc@xyz.com/home/user/import.R")
```

Answer (score 0):

I use samba to create a network drive and then just connect like you normally would to any file on windows.